# Python 3.5 crashes with Exception code: c0000005 on windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.5

EDIT: I had another random error pop up which I successfully caught in command prompt, this time pointing to line 69- segmentation fault calling whether length of a tuple in a different dictionary is equal to a number....

I have a long running (up to a week) script that I designed to test SQLlite3 insert times for different structures. Unfortunately the script intermittently crashes python without outputting error messages to the python GUI, below is the error message that windows gives in the 'python has stopped working' window;

Full error message:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: pythonw.exe
  Application Version:  3.5.150.1013
  Application Timestamp:    55f4dccb
  Fault Module Name:    python35.dll
  Fault Module Version: 3.5.150.1013
  Fault Module Timestamp:   55f4dcbb
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000e800e
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

[Script I was running (warning, 1.5k lines...)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b69cb825fdc6f22d8424)

From observing what had and had not been printed I know that it was caused, or that it at least happened coincidentally at this time, with the following piece of code (starting from line 1450 on the link):

```
with open(r"C:\BMRA\LOG\less tbl log.csv",'a') as log:
   log.write(my_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
   log.write(", ")
   seconds=sql_time.seconds
   log.write(str(seconds))
   log.write("\n")
item_collector=[]
```

The Log csv file appears to have written fine, so my assumption is that the error must lie with the last line.

Item_collector is a (large, ~700mb) dictionary of lists of tuples that had just been written to an sqllite3 database (the tuples containing only str, int, or floats).

As I understand it, the error refers to an application writing to memory it shouldn't and windows consequently shutting everything down to stop it messing things up. However I don't see how changing a normal vanilla python object full of other vanilla python objects should create such an error.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could underlay this, or alternatively ways to figure that out given python doesn't give an error message pointing to the specific issue? I did after a previous issue implement a logging module wrapper below around my script, but it did not catch anything

Some initial research suggested that I get a mini dump from the task manager before closing the process- I have it, but debugging hasn't been succesful- apparently I need something called python35.pdb, which as far as I can make out isn't around (for 3.5)

[The script recently had a similar problem before which gave a similar error message](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3t6weo/how_to_debug_a_long_running_python_script/?)

The advice I received was to implement the logging module around my script as so:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename=r'C:\BMRA\ERROR_LOG.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

try:
    main()                   
except BaseException:
    logging.getLogger(__name__).exception("Program terminated")
    raise
```

and;

```
def logging_decorator(func):
    def wrapper_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.getLogger(__name__).debug(
            "Calling %s: %r %r", func.__name__, args, kwargs)
        ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        logging.getLogger(__name__).debug(
            "%s returned %r", func.__name__, ret)
        return ret
    return wrapper_function


class MyConnect(sqlite3.Connection):
    def cursor(self):
        return super(MyConnect, self).cursor(MyCursor)

    commit = logging_decorator(sqlite3.Connection.commit)


class MyCursor(sqlite3.Cursor):
    execute = logging_decorator(sqlite3.Cursor.execute)
```

However this does not appear to have caught the error, with the script still crashing without sending any info to the designated file.

Apologies if I've not included something necessary.

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner active? It might be worth doing a test with it disabled.

Comment: Worth a shot. An annoying feature of the bug is that it apparently appears in random places in the code (see edit) but that it also appears at random times during a several day run. It ran for 2 days without crashing before, so it's pretty difficult to be sure if something has worked

Comment: The error is `access violation`, so I was wondering if something could be accessing the files whilst you are attempting to write to them.

Comment: Norton anti virus appears to have an 'unauthorised access blocked (access process data)' on it's security history at 3 in the morning- which would be roughly when the script last crashed.

it doesn't mention python though, it says the actor was 'windows\ssystem32\conhost.exe'

Comment: on your point- nothing I've set up would be accessing the files, and the error can happen at times when I'm not actually writing to anything, just doing stuff with python objects in memory

Comment: @Martin Evans turns out the anti-virus was a false hope- unfortunately I have hardware issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the 50th time the script crashed in a random place inexplicably, I ran the windows memory diagnostic tool.

Unfortunately it appears that my system has ram/hardware errors, which I understand would cause issues like this.

Comment: what you mean by system? How do you understand if there is a Hardware error?